# index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `DataTable`, expected `array`. in DataTable

Tags: reactjs

index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `DataTable`, expected `array`.
    in DataTable

render() {
    return (

```
    <DataTable value={this.state.ilac} selectionMode="single" selection={this.state.selectedIlac} onSelectionChange={e => this.setState({ selectedIlac: e.value })} >
      <Column field="id" header="ID"></Column>
      <Column field="ilacAdi" header="İLAÇ ADI"></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </Panel>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning from validating your `DataTable` component's prop `value` (`this.state.ilac`).

The `Datatable` expects an array but `this.state.ilac` is actually an object.

try `Object.values(this.state.ilac)`.

Answer (score -1):

maalesef olmadı.Teşekkürler cevap için